# TOAD 10.6 Sql Error ORA - 01858: What is wrong with query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me identify the below issue.  I have a canned query below and can't get it to run without getting this error:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(fdr_dal_txns.get_txn_trans_adjst_consol
(short_string_col('1BFV')
,'POST_DT'
,short_string_col('MCH','GP3', 'OTC')
,'01-may-2017'
,'30-june-2017'
))
WHERE trd_id_num IN ('17FHKBBSSML',
'17FHVBBRJD8')
```

Comment: I would suggest that you open a new Question with your Query and the Error message you are getting. If you do that, it will be much easier to answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question (there's an `edit` button just below the tags) and include the full text of the error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What is obvious, is that you seem to be passing strings ('01-may-2017' **is** a string) where you should have passed dates. I'd suggest you to use date literals, such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE (fdr_dal_txns.get_txn_trans_adjst_consol (
                 short_string_col ('1BFV'),
                 'POST_DT',
                 short_string_col ('MCH', 'GP3', 'OTC'),
                 DATE '2017-05-01',                           --'01-may-2017',
                 DATE '2017-06-30'                            --'30-june-2017'
               ))
 WHERE trd_id_num IN ('17FHKBBSSML', '17FHVBBRJD8')
```

and see what happens. If it still doesn't help, you should provide much more details of what you're doing (because you told us close to *nothing* so far).